# How to Check if a node is null

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, null, traversal

[image]So I am doing leetcode problem 589. I am just trying to see if i can return the vector when the next node is null. But whenever I run the code I get this error:

Line 933: Char 34: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'struct Node *' (stl_vector.h)

I don't know how to fix this issue.

this node is null in the tree, since root->children[0]->children[0] has no children. But how to I check if root->children[0]->children[0] has no children?

```
  int i=1;
  vector<int> result;
    class Solution {
 public:
     vector<int> preorder(Node* root) {

    if ((root->children[0]->children[0]->children[0])==NULL)
        return result;

     return result;
   }
  };
```

Comment: You've been told before about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Really have no idea how you expect anyone to be able to answer this question from the information given. At the very least you could post the definition of `Node` and explain how a lack of children is representated in your data structure.

Comment: It's also completely unclear how `root->children[0]->children[0]->children[0]` relates to the 'next node', which is apparently what you are trying to check.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're trying to access an out of bounds element somewhere.

Comment: root->children[0]->children[0]->children[0] is supposed to point to the left child of the left most node, I added a picture of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I would think the answer is more carefully than this.  It's difficult to say what you can absolutely guarantee is there in this situation without knowing the rest of your code.  But full paranoia would be something like

```
if (root == NULL || root->children == NULL || root->children[0] == NULL
    || root->children[0]->children == NULL
    || root->children[0]->children[0] == NULL
    || root->children[0]->children[0]->children == NULL
    || root->children[0]->children[0]->children[0] == NULL)
```

I'm pretty sure there's some kind of design flaw here...  I think it's both the fact that there are multiple hops to go through like this, and the thing holding the prior node is `root`, which suggests you're not moving your focus down as you descend the tree, you're just coding more and more steps to get to the elements you're looking at.

Edit: Hint: recursion.  Normally, for homework, I'd prefer to not give much in the way of code examples, but I'm leaving the code I put in above as it is because it primarily demonstrates the failure of your current approach, rather than being something you can really use in your assignment.